# Uploading to BigQuery GIS: "Invalid nesting: loop 1 should not contain loop 0"

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm uploading a CSV file to BigQuery GIS but it fails with "Invalid nesting: loop 1 should not contain loop 0".

This is the error in full:

```
Upload complete.
BigQuery error in load operation: Error processing job 'mytable-1176:bqjob_rc625a5098ae5fb_0000017289ff6c01_1': Error while reading data,
error message: CSV table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1; errors: 1. Please look into the errors[] collection for more details.
Failure details:
- Error while reading data, error message: Could not parse 'POLYGON
((-0.02679766923455 51.8338973454281,-0.02665013926462
51.83390841216...' as geography for field geom (position 0)
starting at location 23 Invalid nesting: loop 1 should not contain
loop 0
```

I've pasted the offending row of the CSV file in full below. It appears to be valid WKT (or at any rate, if I do `SELECT ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON(....)')` in Postgres, or in BigQuery itself, I don't get an error.

I can upload other rows of the CSV file just fine, so this isn't a problem with the schema etc.

My CSV file, in full:

```
"POLYGON ((-0.02679766923455 51.8338973454281,-0.02665013926462 51.8339084121668,-0.026560668613456 51.8339151296535,-0.026487799104821 51.8339205969954,-0.026347243837181 51.8339311509483,-0.026281189190482 51.8339361120738,-0.026195955952021 51.8339425137374,-0.026119198116154 51.8339482752767,-0.026003486068282 51.8339569617883,-0.025952488850356 51.8339607906816,-0.025861270469634 51.8339676401587,-0.025858880441179 51.833967860811,-0.025828348676774 51.8339706933666,-0.025711206268708 51.8339815496773,-0.025689593686264 51.8339835517849,-0.025640538635981 51.8339884382609,-0.025529205899202 51.8339995358046,-0.025488766227802 51.8340035687339,-0.02540224517472 51.8340121962521,-0.025345346891212 51.8340178681142,-0.025335200706554 51.8340188757231,-0.025340349282672 51.834037216355,-0.025358081339574 51.8341162858309,-0.02530239219927 51.8342041307738,-0.025137161521987 51.8344648008,-0.025126602922354 51.8344835251042,-0.025117917332667 51.8344989177765,-0.025112142226516 51.8345091618299,-0.025029432267333 51.8347162751015,-0.025024329062831 51.8347290752289,-0.025009526856435 51.8347661622769,-0.025093294071485 51.8348450548926,-0.025096355164552 51.8348576953871,-0.02509500197774 51.8348697132258,-0.02509108994899 51.8348834865336,-0.025088461171685 51.8348894941415,-0.025083736509161 51.834900277382,-0.025072148729253 51.8349192991243,-0.025066276262158 51.8349271226369,-0.025058952287815 51.8349372687386,-0.025042611052947 51.834953135315,-0.025001680789442 51.8349786422223,-0.024920260658812 51.8350331883359,-0.024784590322317 51.8351240689296,-0.024592664989898 51.8352526349419,-0.024589543101483 51.8352549834202,-0.024520606248935 51.8353068434611,-0.024501351755 51.8353358705759,-0.024471109202685 51.8353814835663,-0.024447518472049 51.8354170560924,-0.024415970917911 51.8354646254313,-0.024417975754184 51.835564067945,-0.024418971386853 51.8356132810276,-0.02441636899482 51.8356607970846,-0.024412069417915 51.8357391278945,-0.024405890624276 51.835851768366,-0.024404645018278 51.8358745876421,-0.024405581774846 51.835921497729,-0.024408752345367 51.8360808568968,-0.024410061546665 51.8361464500484,-0.024413180002599 51.8363030207515,-0.024413726767404 51.8363306539892,-0.0244128839888 51.8363572028036,-0.024408747608483 51.8364878440004,-0.024407687807063 51.8365213401423,-0.024406476329442 51.8365599592925,-0.024391641544557 51.836678011519,-0.024386208097079 51.8367212266961,-0.024342690041741 51.8367069893255,-0.024319288279565 51.8366997621065,-0.024292175040315 51.8366914384262,-0.024256993656756 51.8366804074215,-0.024209378619192 51.8366665867489,-0.024155315566661 51.8366508502892,-0.024105536982117 51.8366373798885,-0.024053478095738 51.8366236103787,-0.024004689328762 51.8366107410593,-0.023970131471096 51.836601716714,-0.023909047139602 51.8365858891387,-0.023872509708533 51.8365763279375,-0.023813366264893 51.8365609285831,-0.023800608538063 51.8365575849119,-0.023784986418606 51.8365536895414,-0.023742454842103 51.8365431193584,-0.023711439553104 51.8365354043849,-0.023694010323261 51.8365310110389,-0.023665520720037 51.8365239589599,-0.023639661080915 51.8365175085891,-0.023621685803881 51.8365129891569,-0.023606995500241 51.8365093612042,-0.023594058239185 51.836506140384,-0.023579988098348 51.8365026037803,-0.023576657648261 51.836501756494,-0.023573212341634 51.8365008803008,-0.023570943037101 51.8365003296066,-0.023566131987943 51.8364991517017,-0.023560820359479 51.836497803524,-0.023550842839 51.836494614457,-0.023534152361942 51.8364892623447,-0.023519322307527 51.8364845169988,-0.02348978408578 51.8364729061891,-0.023475831119834 51.8364673572881,-0.023454784263057 51.8364590634327,-0.023440395773423 51.8364535161996,-0.023420399054051 51.8364457705282,-0.023412745105461 51.8364422248457,-0.023381943124318 51.8364279850281,-0.023357997010233 51.8364146337661,-0.023352306254349 51.8364113368901,-0.023317752798112 51.8363896244224,-0.023286469209969 51.836365503042,-0.023270902824062 51.8363503952582,-0.023271184375594 51.8363476124069,-0.023383603050238 51.836110354259,-0.023465777469187 51.8359369179285,-0.023472651192556 51.8358651407666,-0.023528809877392 51.8357004122102,-0.023529686057616 51.835690679384,-0.023538063914411 51.83565382625,-0.023543689808186 51.835629102312,-0.023572573948308 51.8355021681838,-0.023577786720198 51.8354792537265,-0.023618788068211 51.8352990106071,-0.023627360729621 51.8352613514407,-0.023661334277455 51.8351119863322,-0.023669026973139 51.8350781790229,-0.023688225716162 51.8349937501145,-0.023717627975541 51.8348645765991,-0.023722804894815 51.8348418143991,-0.023756486300809 51.8346938021715,-0.023763907778347 51.8346612132372,-0.023790901015912 51.834542628006,-0.023795341167441 51.8345230996081,-0.023800489727373 51.8345105970367,-0.023838123662149 51.834419158237,-0.023854300226396 51.8343798733486,-0.023881261233424 51.8343143955334,-0.02360425553657 51.8343556996006,-0.023715342137444 51.8343230723896,-0.023748777209506 51.8343116206823,-0.023788430888355 51.8342980344079,-0.023870547343144 51.8342676988052,-0.023942069257488 51.8342416452568,-0.023977465644738 51.8342284909458,-0.024007122432287 51.8342174702501,-0.024015599076738 51.8342144833934,-0.024058719278701 51.8341992917174,-0.024087038370323 51.834189318598,-0.024105922723606 51.8341826669339,-0.024107853809983 51.8341819889956,-0.024165165953312 51.8341609030475,-0.024196280263318 51.834154052201,-0.024216549190068 51.834149590904,-0.02430529023458 51.8341300490434,-0.024364346544379 51.8341175259067,-0.024380183743731 51.8341141681084,-0.024434405357854 51.8341026697566,-0.024448191552983 51.8340997450887,-0.02450384848189 51.8340892779444,-0.024534730584179 51.8340827558198,-0.024571252512039 51.834075051532,-0.024617624661644 51.8340664695984,-0.02465593398552 51.8340593798021,-0.024659169226995 51.8340587507378,-0.024698227325573 51.8340511339728,-0.024715633647968 51.8340477395406,-0.024790094189827 51.8340371025226,-0.024838827806997 51.8340302776774,-0.024900748436463 51.8340216150771,-0.024978773610225 51.8340117751699,-0.025070395982381 51.8340016689899,-0.025162402800403 51.833992063766,-0.02519959947995 51.8339881743187,-0.025258434658431 51.8339820224963,-0.025299537926511 51.8339784144308,-0.025322340623602 51.8339764143945,-0.025367654362725 51.8339724453802,-0.025433566943196 51.833966754013,-0.02546940835365 51.8339636510231,-0.025478048048634 51.8339629058588,-0.025545930176343 51.8339589740019,-0.025596525520343 51.8339560377582,-0.025600745391944 51.8339557938799,-0.025724272639777 51.833947958345,-0.025744834562549 51.8339467478911,-0.025819588005694 51.8339423467392,-0.025865426412415 51.8339396542424,-0.025940870479972 51.8339357232096,-0.026005709012821 51.8339323514664,-0.026011573315888 51.8339320092857,-0.026097210950677 51.833926981359,-0.026163087127967 51.8339231143903,-0.026182935984022 51.8339219458446,-0.02626063552581 51.8339182143234,-0.026381722979675 51.8339123963649,-0.026433135483049 51.8339100220004,-0.026570879650513 51.833903674085,-0.026606068864626 51.8339025380898,-0.026689092338078 51.8338998667835,-0.026732668330249 51.8338984578396,-0.02679766923455 51.8338973454281),(-0.026648986091666 51.8339075655333,-0.026350862668855 51.833928055419,-0.026484565304541 51.8339188701762,-0.026564475458192 51.8339133771113,-0.026648986091666 51.8339075655333),(-0.026648986091666 51.8339075655333,-0.026649000595502 51.8339075657766,-0.02679766923455 51.8338973454281,-0.026648986091666 51.8339075655333),(-0.024985527558019 51.8340129946412,-0.024837331236428 51.8340326354761,-0.024948153517607 51.834017951115,-0.024985527558019 51.8340129946412),(-0.025153445104997 51.8339934420137,-0.025006535825553 51.8340102091839,-0.025133197780121 51.8339957546967,-0.025153445104997 51.8339934420137))"
```

Could this be a winding order problem?

For reference my source data is an EPSG:27700 shapefile, and I converted it to EPSG:4326 WKT CSV using `ogr2ogr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem with polygon orientation, for details see: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/gis-data#polygon_orientation

When loading WKT geography data, BigQuery assumes the polygons are oriented as described in the link above (to allow loading polygons larger than hemisphere).

`ST_GeogFromText` has different default, and that allows it to consume this data. If you pass second parameter `oriented => TRUE` to `ST_GeogFromText` function, you get the same result.

The workaround is to either load data as `STRING` and then convert to Geography using `ST_GeogFromText`, or load using GeoJSON format instead of WKT. GeoJSON is planar map format, so there is no polygon orientation ambiguity.

You can make ogr2ogr produce CSV with GeoJSON using something like

```
ogr2ogr -f csv -dialect sqlite \
  -sql "select AsGeoJSON(ST_Transform(geometry, 4326)) geom, * from shp" 
  out.csv ./input/
```

See also https://medium.com/@mentin/loading-large-spatial-features-to-bigquery-geography-2f6ceb6796df